# El condicionamiento de validación mimes no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo esta vista con la cual envió un email a alguien adjuntándole un `PDF`.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h5>Selecciona un archivo PDF para enviarselo al correo de una empresa</h5><h6>El PDF deberia estar en <b>C:/Users/pcx/Downloads</b></h6></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="pdf_empresa" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo Electronico de la empresa</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="archivo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Archivo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="archivo" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('archivo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="archivo" value="{{ old('archivo') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('archivo'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('archivo') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Enviar Curriculo
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Para manejar dicho formulario, tengo el siguiente request:

```
public function messages(){
    return[
        'email.required'=>'El correo electronico de la empresa es obligatorio', // Recuerda que esto es un vector en el que hay que poner coma entre un elemento de la cadena y otro.
        'email.email'=>'Debe ser una dirección de correo valida',
        'archivo.required'=>'Debes indicar el archivo que adjuntaras',
        'archivo.mimes'=>'Este campo debe apuntar a un fichero PDF'
    ];
}

public function rules(){
    return[
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'archivo'=>'required|mimes:pdf'
    ];
}
```

Este fomulario tiene que comprobar que si el archivo adjunto es de tipo PDF, pero cuando lo pruebo me topo con el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como indico correctamente que debe ser valido con archivos PDF?

Más datos: El archivo Mail que se encarga de enviar el correo electronico:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Adjuntar extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $archivo;

    public function __construct($archivo){
        $this->archivo=$archivo;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('correo.adjunto')->attach('C:/Users/pcx/Downloads/'.$this->archivo);
    }
}
```

Aparte, he logrado que funcione la validación mimes gracias a este cambio en el formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="pdf_empresa" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Pero ahora a cambio el formulario es incapaz de encontrar el PDF y al intentar adjuntarlo al email, mi programa se termina colgando.

Answer (score 1):

La validación está correcta , lo que hace falta es agregar el atributo al formulario para enviar archivos. [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype)

```
<form method="POST" action="pdf_empresa" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Pues cuando lo utilizo consigo que funcione la validación, pero a cambio el programa se cuelga al intentar adjuntarlo en el email.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez a preguntas concretas, respuestas concretas ,  si se cuelga o muestra otro error ya sería  otra pregunta, si hace la edición de su pregunta con mi respuesta , mi respuesta pierde validez. Intente evitar este comportamiento. Saludos

Comment: Pues esta creada la nueva pregunta.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez perfecto, si mi respuesta resolvió su problema inicial puede marcarla como aceptada, Saludos.